# Return count of rows on today's date grouped by the hour w/ 0's for hours with no count

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to get the count of rows within a hour, starting with 12 am to the current hour. I currently am getting the last 24 hours easily, but am unsure how start the series with 2/17/2020 12:00 am up to the current time.

Here is what I have currently returning the last 24 hours where hours with no count return 0:

```
with hour_range as (
    select generate_series(date_trunc('hour', now() - interval '23 hours'), date_trunc('hour', now()), '1 hour':: interval) as hour
),

hour_count as (
    select date_trunc('hour', local_start_time) as hour,
        count (*) as ct
    from call_data.rc_api_call_logs
    where local_start_time::date = current_date -- today
    and br_call_flag = 1
    group by 1
)

select to_char(hour_range.hour, 'Mon DD YYYY HH12:MI:SSam'),
       coalesce(hour_count.ct, 0)
from hour_range
left outer join hour_count on hour_range.hour = hour_count.hour;
```

Also I am just reformatting military time to normal time in my last select for readability. The local_start_time is of **timestamp** type. The issue is really with the generate_series query, and fixing the start time since I am using it to join to get the hours with count 0.

**EDIT:** Any suggestions for performance will be helpful, otherwise I will accept my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did some more research and realized casting current_time to a timestamp gives the current date with 0:00:00 as the timestamp.

Therefore:

```sql
current_date::timestamp -- returns 2020-2-17 00:00:00

select generate_series(date_trunc('hour', current_date::timestamp), 
                       date_trunc('hour', now()), '1 hour':: interval) as hour; -- 2020-2-17 0:00:00 to 2020-2-17 current time
```

As mentioned in the comments by [user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/330315/a-horse-with-no-name), this works as well:

```
current_date + time '00:00:00' -- 2020-2-17 00:00:00
```

Comment: Another option would have been `current_date + time '00:00:00'`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to subtract any interval to get start of range. Just use date_trunc('day',now()). This truncates the time component to "00:00:00".

```
 with hour_range as (
    select generate_series(date_trunc('day', now() ), date_trunc('hour', now()), '1 hour':: interval) as hour
) 
select * from hour_range
```